# Install Windows alongwith ubuntu 13.04

Tags: installation

I have a laptop with ubuntu 13.04 installed in 500gb hard disk. I want to install windows 8 alongside with it(dual boot). I tried installing 13.04 alongside (already existing) windows 8 but failed. so i removed windows 8 and put 13.04 in it. Please help me........

Answer (score 0):

In my experience I installed Windows 8 first, then installed Ubuntu 13.04 (raring) and using GRUB I was able to boot to both operating systems. If the case is that you were able to boot to both previously using an older version of Ubuntu then I suppose you could install a previous version and upgrade via the update manager in the Linux OS.

If you wish to access your Windows partition then you could load the Windows 8 disc and use the CMD to recover the boot manager:

```
bootrec /fixmbr
```

and

```
bootrec /fixboot
```

But your best bet is to install Ubuntu altering the partitions as you install so that you can set the mount point to `/` in the hope that GRUB loads there and allows access to both OS's/